# Horizontal constraints IOS in code for multiple buttons

Tags: ios, visual-format-language

When I am aligning 4 buttons using Visual Format Language in Xcode I added

```
constraintsWithVisualFormat @"V:|-50-[b1]-10-[b2]-10-[b3]-10-[b4]"
```

and It works OK.
But when I try to apply horizontal constraints, I did

```
@"H:|-20-[b1]-20-|"
@"H:|-20-[b2]-20-|"
@"H:|-20-[b3]-20-|"
@"H:|-20-[b4]-20-|"
```

Best solution I came up with is to align them in pairs like

```
@"H:|-20-[b1(==b2)]-20-|"
@"H:|-20-[b3(==b4)]-20-|"
```

Now I'm trying to do it in 1 line of code but no success.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

"|" represents the superview of your [B1] [B2] [B3] [B4] etc. What you would want to do is something similar to what you did for the Vertical Constraints:

```
constraintsWithVisualFormat: @"H:|-?-[B1]-20-[B2]-20-[B3]-20-[B4]-?-|"
```

Edit:
If you want these to be centered in the superview you will need to do some calculations for the "?" in the above answer.

```
CGFloat viewWidth = mySuperviewHere.frame.size.width;
CGFloat totalWidth = B1.frame.size.width + ... + B4.frame.size.width + 3 * 20;

CGFloat marginWidth = (viewWidth + totalWidth) / 2.0;

constraintsWithVisualFormat: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-%f-[B1]-20-[B2]-20-[B3]-20-[B4]-%f-|", marginWidth, marginWidth]
```

Comment: As far as I am concerned this H constraint will set them like
stairs with 20px between each.

Comment: Right, well this how you would do that just ignore the centering part. Accept my answer if it has helped you and is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your third bit of code with 2 lines is ambiguous and would need more code. All that does is position b1 and b2 and then set the width of b3 and b4. It doesn't set the position of b3 or b4 so it is ambiguous.

What doesn't work in the second bit of code (with 4 lines)? That should work.

The best solution by a country mile... use a nib or storyboard to layout the view.

Comment: I want to set all horizontal constraints (make buttons width 40 px less then a view and centered) in 1 line of code (now I have 4 as you noticed). Important thins is that I dont have storyboard.

Comment: Can you put a picture of what you want. It's really hard to tell.